# emacs isearch with automatic application of a regex between characters

Tags: regex, emacs, hook, isearch

I would like to have a hook into Emacs's `isearch-forward` function to make it automatically apply a regex between the input characters while searching a string.  For example, I would like to set this regex to `[-=<>]`.  If I now type `foobar` into isearch, it should match `foo<bar`, `fo=ob=>ar`, `f-o-o-b-a-r`, etc.

Is such a functionality already available?  I looked into ELPA and MELPA without success.  In case this is not available, and since my Elisp abilities are very limited: How could this be implemented?

Comment: Your use of the word "ignore" is confusing to me. It sounds like you want Emacs to automatically invoke `isearch-forward-regexp` and *add* your pattern between each character of the original pattern. The examples are pretty clear about the desired outcome, but the phrasing doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: Right.  Hopefully, it's better now.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution by myself after inspecting `hexl.el` from Emacs.

Here's the code.

```
(defun my-isearch-function ()
  "Make isearch skip characters -=<> while searching."
  (if (not isearch-regexp)
      (lambda (string &optional bound noerror count)
        (funcall
         (if isearch-forward
             're-search-forward
           're-search-backward)
         (mapconcat (lambda (c) (regexp-quote (string c))) string
                    "\\(?:[-=<>]*\\)?")
         bound
         noerror
         count))
    (isearch-search-fun-default)))


(defun toggle-my-isearch ()
  "Toggle my search mode.
If activated, incremental search skips characters -=<> while
searching.

For example, searching `foobar' matches `foo-bar' or `f-o-o=b<a>r'."
  (interactive)
  (if (eq isearch-search-fun-function 'isearch-search-fun-default)
      (progn
        (setq isearch-search-fun-function 'my-isearch-function)
        (message "my isearch on"))
    (setq isearch-search-fun-function 'isearch-search-fun-default)
    (message "my isearch off")))


(global-set-key (kbd "s-s") 'toggle-my-isearch)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a package called [`flex-isearch`](https://bitbucket.org/jpkotta/flex-isearch), that basically inserts ".*" in between each character of the search string (it's a bit more complicated than that) and switches to regexp searching.  It does this automatically when the isearch fails.